# Log4j java version in the end of each line of stack trace

Tags: java, log4j

When I use log4j and do

```
log.error("Exception message", ex);
```

I see something like this

> at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.ensureOpen(HttpURLConnection.java:3366)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_171]    at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3391)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_171]

why do I see java version at the end of each line and how do I get rid of it? Some lines will also have other info, like a path from where the script started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using log4j, you provide a configuration that describes the "pattern" that describes how each "log message" will get formatted.  Part of that pattern can control the format of the stack trace when a throwable is logged.  If you don't provide an explicit format for a throwable, it will use the default one, which is adding the JVM version suffix, as per your example.

Here is a pattern layout which removes the default suffix.

```
 <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n %ex{suffix()}"/>
```

The details are available here - https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html.

Comment: Which conversion pattern includes the JRE version?

Comment: The pattern %xEx logs the throwable (if one was provided to the logger) and includes the "class versioning information".  For classes in the JRE, that prints the version of the JRE.